# java - how to iterate through maps in order

Tags: java, maps

This is the code:

```
for(String key : mymap.stringPropertyNames()) {
//mycode
}
```

This works correctly but I noticed I get the values I need in random order, is there a way to loop through the map using a particular order?

EDIT: `Mymap` is a `properties` object.

Comment: That depends on what `mymap` is.

Comment: @Ciurga, Which map you're using? you need to use TreeMap inorder to store and iterate the contents based upon some logical ordering

Comment: mymap actually is a properties object

Comment: Do you want a `Map` that respects the order in which the elements were originally inserted, such as `LinkedHashMap`, or do you want a `Map` which sorts the keys in a particular order, such as `TreeMap`?

Comment: @DavidWallace i need something like `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: Right.  Looks like you've got your answer then.  May I suggest that you mark one of the answers here as accepted, by clicking on the tick mark?  That way, everyone knows that you don't need more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using a `Map` without sorting like [`HashMap`](http://This%20class%20makes%20no%20guarantees%20as%20to%20the%20order%20of%20the%20map;%20in%20particular,%20it%20does%20not%20guarantee%20that%20the%20order%20will%20remain%20constant%20over%20time.)

> [...] **This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map;** in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant **over time**.

---

Instead of this, you can use some concrete implementation like:

[`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

[`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you need *no duplicates*...

> `Hash` table and linked list implementation of the `Map` interface, with predictable iteration order.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll change the code

Comment: @Ciurga if you need to loop them mantaining the order and you don't need to access them by key consider to use a List instead.

Comment: @Ciurga as this is your first question you must know if **this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)** by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and **gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself**. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want predictable iteration order (insertion order) then use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

If you want the elements to be sorted you need to use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) , in this case the Keys need to implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface

Answer (score 1):

Either change the Map implementation into one of the ones that support ordering or sort the keys before iterating over them. I am a bit confused though, normally one gets the keys of a map by the `keySet` method. I am not familiar with `stringPropertyNames` but if it is a Map you should be able to do something like (untested code):

```
List keys = new ArrayList(mymap.keySet())
Collections.sort(keys)
for ( String key : keys ) {
    [...]
}
```